# Chartjs hide dataset legend v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js3

My current graphs on the webpage are powered by Chart.js v2.5.3. Charts that were configured a while ago works perfectly fine. Here is the code:

```
var ctw = document.getElementById("chart-budget");
var myChart = new Chart(ctw, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["budget", "costs"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Amount",
      data: [520980, 23397.81],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(143, 211, 91, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(143, 211, 91,1)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false,
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

As v3 is now available I was thinking to switch to it. A quick test revealed some issues I will need to overcome. One of the issue I'm struggling with is unability to hide dataset legend. In V2.5 it was done by `options.legend.display` set to *false* but not any longer.
In [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html) I did not come across anything that could help me.

Is there anyone who can advice on how to hide a legend in Chart.js V3?

/Kuba

Comment: Can you try configuring these options? 

options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
   }
}

Comment: @Ravikumar That's exactly it, if you post that as an answer it should be accepted

Comment: Thanks @noppa, moved it to answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Configuring option like below would solve the problem in V3 version.

```
options: { plugins: { legend: { display: false }, } }
```

Comment: confirmed this works with Chart.js 4.3 (despite what their documentation says)

Answer (score 3):

In **Chart.js V3** you can add a `filter` function to [`options.plugins.legend.labels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) and evaluate either the labels or their `datasetIndex` values to suppress **specific** legends rather than **ALL** of them.

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: function(legendItem, data) {
          let label = data.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
          if (typeof(label) !== 'undefined') {
            if (legendItem.datasetIndex >= 3){
              return false;
            }
          }
          return label;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```